# Build error on AndroidLocationPlayServiceManager

Tags: java, android, google-play, codenameone

My latest build is failing. I have   android.includeGPlayServices=true in the build hints. This was actually working fine two or three days ago, so not sure what is causing it. Am using google maps in my app using the google cn1 lib. :

```
/tmp/build6792756217656774137xxx/Marketta/src/main/java/com/andira/mobile/MarkettaStub.java:51: error: cannot find symbol
com.codename1.impl.android.AndroidNativeUtil.addLifecycleListener(com.codename1.location.AndroidLocationPlayServiceManager.getInstance());
                                                                                        ^
  symbol:   class AndroidLocationPlayServiceManager
  location: package com.codename1.location
/tmp/build6792756217656774137xxx/Marketta/src/main/java/com/andira/mobile/MarkettaStub.java:52: error: cannot find symbol
com.codename1.social.GoogleImpl.init();
                    ^
  symbol:   class GoogleImpl
  location: package com.codename1.social
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
2 errors
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possibly caused by the latest separation of the GooglPlayServices into individual libraries.

You will need additional build hints to make that work. Specifically these:

```
android.playService.maps=true
android.playService.location=true
```

Though it was stated that if you add none these, everything would be added by default. Try that to see if it fixes your issue.

Read more about these changes on codemane one blog [here](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/a-thank-you-an-important-update-on-android-builds.html).